# Impala on Cloudera CDH "Could not create logging file: Permission denied"

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I installed Impala via a parcel in the Cloudera Manager 4.5 on a CDH 4.2.0-1.cdh4.2.0.p0.10 cluster.

When I try to start the service it fails on all nodes with this message

```
    perl -pi -e 's#{{CMF_CONF_DIR}}#/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/800-impala-IMPALAD#g' /run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/800-impala-IMPALAD/impala-conf/impalad_flags
    '[' impalad = impalad ']'
    exec /opt/cloudera/parcels/IMPALA-0.6-1.p0.109/lib/impala/../../bin/impalad --flagfile=/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/800-impala-IMPALAD/impala-conf/impalad_flags
Could not create logging file: Permission denied
COULD NOT CREATE A LOGGINGFILE 20130326-204959.15015!log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/impalad/impalad.INFO (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
...
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.<clinit>(FileSystem.java:92)
+ date
```

[Complete StdErr Log](http://pastebin.com/tw9M1xkz)

I'm unsure whether the permission issue is cause of Impala not running or whether something else crashes and the permission issues just comes up because the crash log can not be written.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run impala from debug binaries as described here:

https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-160

Seems to be related to the JVM in Kernel 12.04.1 LTS

Original Answer: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/impala-user/4MRZYbn5hI0